# Android consmindo web service soap

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

Estou com dificuldades em consumir um web services *SOAP* do tipo complexo,
Como eu poderia enviar essa requisição, Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento mobile.

```
<Autenticacao xsi:type="urn:Autenticacao" xmlns:urn="urn:RouterBoxMobile">
     <ChaveIntegracao xsi:type="xsd:string">?</ChaveIntegracao>
</Autenticacao>
```

Comment: Acabei de fazer essas duas Vídeo aulas [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J87qN3B-dI). Usa exatamente o SOAP como base! Pra mim foi muito útil! Pra você pode ser também!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile","ListaDetalhe");


SoapObject chaveIntegracao = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile","ListaDetalhe");

chaveIntegracao.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao","?");
request.addProperty("Autenticacao",chaveIntegracao);
```